# How to inject the activity with every thing loaded?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I want to inject my activity class into another third party class like below,

```
public class LoginPresenter implements ILoginPresenter {
@Inject
LoginActivity view;
public void attemptLogin(String username, String password) {
if (view.getUserName().isEmpty()) {
//"view" here is always null, I dont know how to correctly inject it.
        view.showUserNameEmptyError(R.string.USER_NAME_EMPTY_ERROR);
        return;
    }
}
```

**this is my appModule class which provides a big context for me here,**

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
static Application mApplication;

public AppModule(Application application) {
    mApplication = application;

}

@Provides
@Singleton
Application providesApplication() {

    return mApplication;
}
}
```

can I cast the above context into one of the activities, into constructor of my class, if yes how so?, Or should I define another provider for it?

**this is my component**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, NetModule.class})
public interface NetComponent {

    void inject(LoginPresenter presenter);

    void inject(ILoginPresenter presenter);
}
```

UPDATE:
I added this constructor and provider for it, to my Appmodule

```
public AppModule(Application application, LoginActivity loginActivity) {
  this.application = application;
  this.loginActivity = loginActivity;
}
```

but i don't know,how to pass the parameter to build the component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add another provider method.

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
  private final Application application;
  private final LoginActivity loginActivity;

  public AppModule(Application application, LoginActivity loginActivity) {
    this.application = application;
    this.loginActivity = loginActivity;
  }

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  Application providesApplication() {
    return mApplication;
  }

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  LoginActivity provideLoginActivity() {
    return loginActivity;
  }
}
```

Comment: but how Am i gonna pass the context? DaggerNetComponent.builder()
.appModule(new AppModule(this,/*what should i do here?*/))

Comment: You would have to build your AppModule in LoginActivity, and add "this" for second parameter.

Comment: thank you, but what would I do about the first parameter then, I Updated My question

Comment: you could do (Application) getApplicationContext();